# Is there a exponential law for categories?

Tags: category-theory

I wonder whether the following statement is true or not：
Let $\mathcal C,\mathcal D,\mathcal E$ be categories, then the functor category $({\mathcal C}^{\mathcal D})^{\mathcal E}$ is equivalent to both $\mathcal C^{\mathcal D\times\mathcal E}$ and $({\mathcal C}^{\mathcal E})^{\mathcal D}$. 
I am afraid that it involves something in set theory which I cannot deal with so I ask for your help.

Comment: As long as your foundations prove all those categories exist, there is no problem set theoretically.

Comment: There's nothing special about categories here. These equivalences hold in any Cartesian closed category.